# Java: Strings: Not giving a good result

Tags: java, string, query-by-example

I am trying this textbook example, and I checked, this is exactly what was in the book:-

```
public class StringBuilderConstructors
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Object objectRef = "hello";
    String string = "goodbye";
    char[] charArray = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
    boolean booleanValue = true;
    char characterValue = 'Z';
    int integerValue = 7;
    long longValue = 10000000000L;
    float floatValue = 2.5f;
    double doubleValue = 33.333;

    StringBuilder lastBuffer = new StringBuilder("last buffer");
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    buffer.append(objectRef)
    .append(System.getProperty("line.seperator"))
    .append(string)
    .append(System.getProperty("line.seperator"))
    .append(charArray)
    .append(System.getProperty("line.seperator"))
    .append(booleanValue)
    .append(System.getProperty("line.seperator"))
    .append(characterValue)
    .append(System.getProperty("line.seperator"))
    .append(integerValue)
    .append(System.getProperty("line.seperator"))
    .append(longValue)
    .append(System.getProperty("line.seperator"))
    .append(floatValue)
    .append(System.getProperty("line.seperator"))
    .append(doubleValue)
    .append(System.getProperty("line.seperator"))
    .append(lastBuffer);

    System.out.printf("buffer contains%n%s %n", buffer.toString());
  }
}
```

But the result it is giving me is completely wrong.

buffer contains
hellonullgoodbyenullabcdefnulltruenullZnull7null10000000000null2.5null33.333nulllast buffer

This whole thing is not supposed to be in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are using `System.getProperty("line.seperator")` instead use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` , you are simple using `seperator` instead of `separator` typo i guess.Elliot already answered the other way of doing things, to add to your answer. I would prefer following code:

```
String lineSeparator=System.getProperty("line.separator");
buffer.append(objectRef)
.append(lineSeparator)
.append(string)
.append(lineSeparator)
.append(charArray)
.append(lineSeparator)
.append(booleanValue)
.append(lineSeparator)
.append(characterValue)
.append(lineSeparator)
.append(integerValue)
.append(lineSeparator)
.append(longValue)
.append(lineSeparator)
.append(floatValue)
.append(lineSeparator)
.append(doubleValue)
.append(lineSeparator)
.append(lastBuffer);
```

I prefer reusing the code, i think it make the code more robust.

Answer (score 2):

This `System.getProperty("line.seperator")` is not correct, you wanted [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) like

```
buffer.append(objectRef) //
        .append(System.lineSeparator()) //
        .append(string) //
        .append(System.lineSeparator()) //
        .append(charArray) //
        .append(System.lineSeparator()) //
        .append(booleanValue) //
        .append(System.lineSeparator()) //
        .append(characterValue) //
        .append(System.lineSeparator()) //
        .append(integerValue) //
        .append(System.lineSeparator()) //
        .append(longValue) //
        .append(System.lineSeparator()) //
        .append(floatValue) //
        .append(System.lineSeparator()) //
        .append(doubleValue) //
        .append(System.lineSeparator()) //
        .append(lastBuffer);
```

Or eliminate `buffer` and use the final `printf` directly (note `printf` translates `%n` appropriately) like

```
System.out.printf("buffer contains%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n", 
        objectRef, string, new String(charArray), booleanValue, 
        characterValue, integerValue, longValue, floatValue, doubleValue, 
        lastBuffer);
```